# Steam - Redirect last visited page after login

Tags: php, authentication, redirect, openid, steam

I am working with https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication 
and I am trying to get the user back to the last page he visited, after login
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `$steamauth['loginpage'] = "";` to the URL of the page you want to return to from Steam, this is located in `steamauth/SteamConfig.php` on line 6.

If you absolutely can find no other way, you can hardcode the return URL into `/steamauth/openid.php`, on line 797 AND 812, replace `$this->returnUrl` and `$returnUrl` with the URL you wish the user to return to.

Answer (score 0):

```
  header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    exit;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

This will send you back to the previous page.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not that. When the user is authorized, it passes several pages for authorization. This code send back to auth steam page